# Drop whitespace only between digits and non digits - Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I'm trying to drop the whitespace between digits and non digits, somehting like this:

```
medication_component

CLORIDRATO DE TRAMADOL 37.5 MG E PARACETAMOL 325 MG
ATEZOLIZUMABE 1.200 MG
ATENOLOL 25 MG
DUPILUMABE 175 MG/ML
CLORETO DE SODIO 2.34 MG/ML E CLORETO DE POTASSIO 1.49 MG/ML E CITRATO DE SODIO 1.96 MG/ML E GLICOSE 19.83 MG/ML
```

```
new_medication_component

CLORIDRATO DE TRAMADOL 37.5MG E PARACETAMOL 325MG
ATEZOLIZUMABE 1.200MG
ATENOLOL 25MG
DUPILUMABE 175MG/ML
CLORETO DE SODIO 2.34MG/ML E CLORETO DE POTASSIO 1.49MG/ML E CITRATO DE SODIO 1.96MG/ML E GLICOSE 19.83MG/ML
```

To do this, I am using a regex where I apply the sintax to drop the whitespace whenever it is between one or more digits and non digits:

```
regexp_replace(medication_component, '(\d+)\s(\D)', '$1$2') as new_medication_component
```

However, the ouput of new_medication_component remains the same as medication_component

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Try escaping the backslashes: `'(\\d+)\\s(\\D)'`

Answer (score 1):

Use double backslashes for the digit and non-digit operators:

```
'(\\d+)\\s(\\D)'
```

So the query should be:

```
regexp_replace(medication_component, '(\\d+)\s(\\D)', '$1$2') as new_medication_component
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html):

> Escape the operator using two backslashes (`'\\'`).

Comment: To work perfectly, double backslashes should also be before the space operator: (\\d+)\\s(\\D)

Comment: @Mariana oops. answer updated.